# List view radio buton not selecting when selected

Tags: flutter

When i run the program on a device when i tick 2nd or 3rd term it does not take effect.

I am developing an Electronic student attendance tracking system so i decided to use a radio to track the term and also use check box to track the attendance that is checked if the student is present and unchecked if the student is not present but when i check the term radio it gives the correct output on the console but does not take effect on the physical screen.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:atttendance_register/dataFiles/pupils.dart';
import 'package:atttendance_register/dataFiles/attendance.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class attendance extends StatefulWidget {

  static Future<void> show(BuildContext context) async {
    await Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>attendance(),fullscreenDialog: true),
    );
  }
  @override
  _attendanceState createState() => _attendanceState();
}

class _attendanceState extends State<attendance> {

//  final List<Pupils> pupils =[
//    Pupils('John', ' Doe', 'Brad', 'Male', '001', DateTime.now(), '21'),
//    Pupils('Jane', ' Doe', 'Mary', 'Female', '002', DateTime.now(), '21'),
//    Pupils('Mohamed', ' James', '', 'Male', '003', DateTime.now(), '33'),
//    Pupils('Titus', ' Nabieu', 'Jusu', 'Male', '004', DateTime.now(), '21'),
//    Pupils('Steven', ' kai', 'Rogers', 'Male', '005', DateTime.now(), '21'),
//    Pupils('Josephine', ' Bah', 'Neneh', 'Female', '006', DateTime.now(), '23')
//
//  ];


  final List<Attendance> attendance =[
    Attendance(false,'John Doe Brad',DateTime.now(),0),
    Attendance(true,'Jane Doe Mary',DateTime.now(),2),
    Attendance(false,'Mohamed James',DateTime.now(),1),
    Attendance(false,'Titus Nabieu Jusu',DateTime.now(),2),
    Attendance(false,'Steven kai Rogers',DateTime.now(),2),
    Attendance(false,'Josephine  Bah Neneh',DateTime.now(),1)
  ];

  bool selectedCheck = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Enter Attendance'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue[900],
      ),

      backgroundColor: Colors.blue[100],

      body:Container(
        child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount:attendance.length,
                itemBuilder:(BuildContext context, int index){
                  int selectedRadio = attendance[index].Term;
                  bool selectedCheck = attendance[index].attendance;
                  return Container(
                    child: Card(
                      child: Column(

                      //final pupil =pupils[index];
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(attendance[index].pupilName),
                          Text('Select Term'),
                          Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Radio(
                                value:0,
                                groupValue: selectedRadio,
                                activeColor: Colors.blue,
                                onChanged: (T){
                                  print(T);
                                  setState(() {selectedRadio = T;}
                                  );},
                              ),
                              new Text(
                                  '1st Term'

                              ),
                              new Radio(
                                value: 1,
                                groupValue: selectedRadio,
                                activeColor: Colors.blue,
                                onChanged: (T){
                                  print(T);
                                  setState(() {selectedRadio = T;}
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
                              new Text(
                                  '2nd Term'
                              ),
                              new Radio(
                                value: 2,
                                groupValue: selectedRadio,
                                activeColor: Colors.blue,
                                onChanged: (T){
                                  print(T);
                                  setState(() {selectedRadio = T;}
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
                              new Text(
                                '3rd Term',
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Checkbox(
                                value: selectedCheck,
                                activeColor: Colors.blue,
                                onChanged: (bool value){
                                  print(value);
                                  setState(() {selectedCheck = value;}
                                  );},
                              ),
                              new Text(
                                  'Present'
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                } ,),
      ),
    );
  }

//  Widget pupilsCard(BuildContext context, int index){
//    final pupil =pupils[index];
//    bool selectedRadio = false;
//
//    return Container(
//      child: Card(
//        child: Column(
//          children: <Widget>[
//            Text(pupil.FirstName+' '+pupil.OtherName+' '+pupil.LastName),
//            Text('Select Term'),
//            Row(
//              children: <Widget>[
//
//
//              ],
//            ),
//            Checkbox(
//              value: selectedRadio,
//              activeColor: Colors.blue,
//              onChanged: (bool value){
//                print(value);
//                setState(() {selectedRadio = value;}
//                );},
//            ),
//            new Text(
//                'Present'
//
//            ),
//          ],
//        ),
//      ),
//    );
//  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `onChanged` property of your `Radio` widgets and your `Checkbox` widget, you are assigning the user selected value to the variable `selectedRadio` / `selectedCheck` and here is the problem, because when the new `State` is created through `setState`, the `ListView` is rebuilding and you are reassigning `selectedRadio` / `selectedCheck` the old value of the objects in this lines:

```
int selectedRadio = attendance[index].Term;
bool selectedCheck = attendance[index].attendance;
```

So you were not changing the actual value of the `objects` in the `List`, but you have too:

```
onChanged: (T) {
    print(T);
    setState(() => attendance[index].Term = T);
},
```

and

```
onChanged: (value) {
    print(value);
    setState(() => attendance[index].attendance = value);
},
```

Comment: i have changed the the code to  "onChanged: (T) {
    print(T);
    setState(() => attendance[index].Term = T);
},  "  but it gives me the error attendance cant be used as setter because its a type Final

Comment: in Dart it is possible to change the values inside a final List, I don't know what the getter Term is returning, but if you want to modify the Term value of the object you should not mark it as final in your Attendance class